# Regular Expression PHP

Tags: php, preg-match

Suppose I have a string like this "EUR 5,00 paid by Robert. EUR 500,00 Paid By Alberto Del Rio.". I want to extract the output like this using regular expression.

Output :

array(
      [0]=>EUR 5,00
      [1]=>EUR 500,00
)

Comment: Have you got a regular expresion that you have tried?

Answer (score 7):

```
$results = array();
preg_match_all("/EUR [0-9,.]+/", $input_string, $results);
```